# How do I create SQL PIVOT column names by aggregating row values?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am guessing that this needs to be done with dynamic sql, but I would prefer a simple query if it is possible.  Searches so far have shown me some examples, but I am totally new to pivot tables and I'm probably not seeing the forest for the trees.  Thanks for any help.

I have a table that looks like this where the 'begin' and 'end' columns can contain basically arbitrary numbers (it's graph data and those are the node numbers).

```
graph_id    begin   end distance
597857  145 147 2.59
601978  107 147 2.86
596794  107 147 2.92
601978  145 147 2.98
601635  145 147 3.06
601635  107 257 3.06
599472  147 151 3.21
601635  107 147 3.29
601978  107 257 3.31
596794  107 257 3.32
```

I want to create a table that looks like this, basically where each row is a graph and each column is an edge:

```
graph_id    145:147 107:147 107:157 147:151 107:257
597857  2.59    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
596794  NULL    2.92    NULL    NULL    3.32
601978  2.98    2.86    NULL    NULL    3.31
601635  3.06    3.29    NULL    NULL    3.06
599472  NULL    NULL    NULL    3.21    NULL
```

Any help is appreciated; I am not sure how to construct the proper aggregations and my brain refuses to wrap itself around pivot tables.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in two different static queries with one caveat: you have to have a list of all the possible "beginning:end" possibilities. You could compile this list by running:

```
select distinct cast([begin] as varchar(10)) + ':' + cast([end] as varchar(10)) as begin_end
from yourtable
```

Then you take these values and paste them, bracketed, into the query below.

```
with cte1 as (select graph_id, cast([begin] as varchar(10)) + ':' + cast([end] as varchar(10)) as begin_end, distance
              from yourtable)

select *
from cte1
pivot (
   max ([distance])                                                   
   for begin_end in ([145:147], [107:147], [107:257], [147:151]))         
   as graphtable
```

You would have to change the list of "beginning:end" values every time you ran it if you expect them to change. If you missed one you wouldn't see it in the results. This may or may not be impractical for your application. Otherwise you need a dynamic SQL query.